# How to return HTML tag from javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of data displayed using **ng-repeat**.
I'm thinking that if it is possible to return HTML tag, it would be easier.
Like this:

```
return '<span class="redHour">'+diffHours+'</span>;
```

but this does't work.

I have this HTML code:

```
<li><p class="table-data3" id="normal-hour">{{RT(order.purchaseTime)}}</p>  </li>
```

If the calculated purchase time is less than 4 I want the color of the **p** becomes red.

Function

```
$scope.RT = function(order) {
var timeDifference;
var currentDate;
var deadLine;
var diffDays;
var diffHours;
var diffMinutes;

currentDate = new Date();
deadLine = new Date(parseInt(order)); // setting purchase time Date Object
deadLine = new Date(deadLine.setDate(deadLine.getDate()+1)); // setting purchase time Date Object + 1 day
timeDifference = (deadLine.getTime()) - (currentDate.getTime()); // deadline data minus current date
var diffDays = Math.floor(timeDifference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var diffHours = Math.floor(timeDifference / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var diffMinutes = Math.floor((timeDifference-(diffHours*(1000 * 60 * 60))) / (1000 * 60));


    if(diffHours <= 4){
       //WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE?
    }
    if (diffHours == 0 && diffMinutes > 0) {
        return diffMinutes +" Mins";
    }else if (diffHours <= 0) {
        diffHours = 0;
        return diffHours;
    }else if (diffHours == 1) {
        return diffHours + " Hour";
    }else {
        return diffHours +" Hours";
    }
}
```

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement filter:

```
app.filter('hoursNow', function () {
    return function (ts) {
      var timeDifference = Date.now() - ts;
      var diffDays = Math.floor(timeDifference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var diffHours = Math.floor(timeDifference / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var diffMinutes = Math.floor((timeDifference-(diffHours*(1000 * 60 * 60))) / (1000 * 60));

      if (diffHours < 4) {
        return '<span class="red">'+diffHours+'hrs</span>';
      }
      return '<span class="green">'+diffHours+'hrs</span>';
    }
});
```

And use it with `ng-bind-html`:

```
<p ng-bind-html="order.purchaseTime | hoursNow"></p>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sp8z5uvj/)

Comment: It works fine.  Thank you so much sir vp_arth! God bless :)

Answer (score 0):

Your $scope.RT function could return a CSS class and the value itself. You can add the CSS class to the p tag in your template to change the styling according to the value.

Comment: See @ebinmanuval answer for a code example. I'm not that familiar with AngularJs

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-style` in your DOM

```
<li><p class="table-data3" id="normal-hour" ng-style="setColor(order)">{{RT(order.purchaseTime)}}</p>  </li>
```

in controller

```
$scope.setColor = function(order){
  var color;
  //Do your math
 return{ 'background-color': color}
}
```

Comment: Thank you! :) God bless.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your method to return object and use [ngInit directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit). Your method can return Object with properties `{'text': String, 'display_red': Boolean}`.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in date" ng-init="item_info = RT(item.purchaseTime)">
  <li ng-class="{inRed: item.displayRed}">
    <span class="table-data3" id="normal-hour">{{item.text}}</span> 
  </li>
</div>
```

Also I've used [ngClass directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) to dynamically assign css class `inRed`, so you have to add such css class to.

Also below is modified if..else from $scope.RT function:

```
var result = {'displayRed': False};
if(diffHours <= 4){
   result['displayRed'] = True;
}
if (diffHours == 0 && diffMinutes > 0) {
    result['text'] = diffMinutes +" Mins";
}else if (diffHours <= 0) {
    diffHours = 0;
    result['text'] = diffHours;
}else if (diffHours == 1) {
    result['text'] = diffHours + " Hour";
}else {
    result['text'] = diffHours +" Hours";
} 
return result
```